# how to display the listviews as cover flow in Android

Tags: android, listview, coverflow

I am new to Android programming.I tried the cover flow example for rotating image views by using below link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

But my requirement is to rotate the multiple list views data.Is it possible to do using this Carousel.Please tell me how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code in the link rotates images. i tried it before and it works fine.

Comment: But I have to display the listviews.Please give me suggestion .

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip. Try this link

Comment: I tried it but is of displaying images as cover flow.But I should display the 4 listviews as cover flow.Is it possible?

Comment: displaying the contents of listview using the above link.